# How do I prevent Windows from using my monitor via USB

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-hub

I have two laptop computers, one for work and one for play.  Recently I decided to install MS Windows on my "play" computer - I know basically nothing about Windows, but I struggled to make the game work, so Windows was going to solve all my problems.

It seems though that Windows isn't as smart about knowing and remembering which path to use to access the external monitor.

The setup is as follow:

```
       /----> HDMI ---------------------> HDMI-switch ---> HDMI -->Monitor
ComputerX                                      ^  
       \----> USB ---> USB-hub --> HDMI out ---+
                          \
                           \--- Mouse, Headphones and other USB devices
```

ComputerX is either my Play or my Work computer, depending on which one I'm using at that moment.  So there are two paths from my computer to the screen - one via the USB hub and one via the direct cable.

The direct cable has an advantage in terms of performance, but I do not have an HDMI port on my work computer (and graphics performance isn't a big issue there), so in that case only the USB cable is connected and there is only one path to the screen.

Here is the problem:
When I boot into Windows on the play computer, firstly if either the Hub or the HDMI cable is plugged in, I get all kinds of issues that get resolved only by unplugging both cables and rebooting.  But worse, it is almost as if Windows prefers to use the screen via USB.  This sometimes causes the screen to start turing on and off every 5 seconds.  This is also only resolved by rebooting and then plugging in the HDMI cable before plugging in the USB cable.

I don't even know how to begin searching for solutions to this issue.  I imagine some kind of way to blacklist the monitor via USB on my play computer would be the answer.

For the record I don't have this issue with Linux, it just works, so this comes as a bit of a surprise.